# find the interval and convergence ratio of a function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Im trying to find the convergence interval and ratio for the function $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{9+x^2}}$. I found the Taylor series which is $\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^5}{54}+\frac{x^7}{648}-...$ However, I don't know how to express it in the sigma notation for finding the interval and ratio

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, *Welcome to the site !*

To make life a bit easier, let $x=3t$ to make

$$\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{9+x^2}}=9 \frac {t^3}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$$ Now, the binomial theorem
$$\frac {1}{\sqrt{1+y}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}\, y^n$$ Now, make $y=t^2$ and then $t=\frac x 3$.